# SwiftUI - NavigationView Error message - Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to implement a really basic NavigationView in SwiftUI.  When I try the sample code that I have seen on other websites it generates an error message in Xcode.  I am not sure why or how to fix this.

I have tried to clean the project, quit Xcode-Beta and restart it but that did not work.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("This is a great app")
        }
    }
}
```

I thought the code above should work but the error I get says:

"Argument passed to call that takes no arguments."

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Compiles fine on my end - the error could be elsewhere. Clang errors are a bit misleading at the moment.

Comment: @MatteoPacini thanks!  You gave me an idea of starting again with a clean Xcode Project and this solved the problem.  Still a bit odd but given that we are in the beta stage, I will add this solution to my toolkit and immediately test things in a clean project if they should be working.

Comment: A simple "Product > Clean Build Folder" did it for me.

Answer (score 10):

I had this same error message too and figured out what I did wrong and then kind of felt like an idiot. Ha ha.

Take a look:
[image: Error]

**It took me a while to figure out that my struct was the same name as a previously defined struct `VStack`.** Whoops!

So I'm wondering if you had a file in your project that did this too.

Answer (score 9):

**VStack can only take 10 argument.**
If more, there will be error, so you should make it nested.

from

```
VStack{

}
```

to

```
VStack{
    VStack{
    }
    VStack{
    }  
}
```

Comment: For a fun little story, I was just browsing through Swift after having tried to learn it about a year ago and now just jumping back in. I distinctly recall about a year ago following a tutorial and adding in a spacer only to have it throw an error and being SO CONFUSED. Little did I know, the answer was as simple as I exceeded the argument limit. Great stuff

Answer (score 5):

Testing Xcode 11.2.1 and it's still buggy. I noticed when I keep adding primitive views to my ContentView, I start getting errors like
"Argument passed to call that takes no arguments",
"Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" etc. on primitive views which worked before.
When I replaced, for example,

```
ScrollView {
            VStack {
        Text
        Button
        Image
        Text
        Button
        Image
        Text
        Button
        Image
        ...
        }
    }
```

with

```
       ScrollView {
            VStack {
        VStack {
            Text
            Button
            Image
        }
        VStack {
            Text
            Button
            Image
        }
        VStack {
            Text
            Button
            Image
        }
        ...
        }
```

my code started to compile and run again.

Answer (score 5):

check-in your app is there any Swifui class with the name  NavigationView.
also when you jump to the definition from NavigationView it should refer to:

```
  @available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 7.0, *)
  public struct NavigationView<Content> : View where Content : View {

  public init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content)

/// The type of view representing the body of this view.
///
/// When you create a custom view, Swift infers this type from your
/// implementation of the required `body` property.
public typealias Body = Never
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem when I accidentally try to redefine Text struct. Check if you naming your custom class the same as those in SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

@Matteo Pacini helped me find the answer.  When I started a new Xcode Project just to test the code above everything worked.  I had a lot of files and was testing a lot of different code while experimenting with SwiftUI in my other project and for some reason XCode was always generating this error.

When I tried everything in a new project it worked.  Something to be aware of while testing.  Hope this helps others avoid similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Embed the 'Text("This is a great app")' in a VStack

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
          Stack {
            Text("This is a great app")
          }
        }
    }
}
```